# LAMP - PHP not submitting field to itself successfully

Tags: php

I have a single field on a webpage that I'm trying to have submit to itself, I think. I can sign into the MySQL server and execute a 'hard coded' query successfully, but I want to be able to enter a small string like 'tur' or 'maeb'. I believe my problem lies somewhere in my PHP, not in my Apache or SQL server.

```
<form method="post" action="search_dmps.php?go" id="searchform">
 <input type="text" name="name">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>

    <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      if(isset($_GET['go'])) {
         echo '$_GET';
         if(preg_match("/[A-Za-z]+/", $_POST['name'])) {
            $name=$_POST['name'];
            // creds
            require 'sql_creds.php';
            // connect to db
            $db=mysqli_connect ("$server", "$user", "$pass") or die ('Failed to connect to server because: ' . mysqli_error());
            // select db
            $ufdb=mysqli_select_db("uf_cs");
            // sql query
            $sql="SELECT * FROM dmps WHERE room RLIKE '" . $name . "'";
            // go execute the query
            $result=mysqli_query($sql);
            // echo table headers
                echo '<table><tr>
               <th>DMPS ID</th>
               <th>Room</th>
               <th>Networked</th>
               <th>IP Address</th>
               <th>MAC Address</th>
               <th>Port Number</th>
               <th>IP Setup</th>
               <th>Notes</th>
               </tr>';
            // while loop to run through the result
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
               echo '
               <tr>
               <td>'.$row['dmps_id'].'</td>
               <td>'.$row['room'].'</td>
               <td>'.$row['networked'].'</td>
               <td>'.$row['ip_address'].'</td>
               <td>'.$row['mac_address'].'</td>
               <td>'.$row['port_number'].'</td>
               <td>'.$row['ip_setup'].'</td>
               <td>'.$row['notes'].'</td>
               </tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
         }
         else {
            echo "Enter a search query";
     }
  }
}
?>
```

I can add anything else that is needed. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: The problem I'm having is after hitting my 'Submit' button, the page flashes and displays the table headers, but everything is blank. This is what leads me to believe the query is executing, but what's being passed into the $name is blank, not what is typed into the field.

Comment: method is post. I had a coworker help me with this PHP since I am still pretty new to it

Comment: please, show your form.

Comment: Added my form above the php

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in $result=mysqli_query($sql);  is the first error I'm getting that's causing an error following it... What does this mean? Isn't mysqli_fetch_array pulling what is a mysqli_query from above it?

Comment: @ShadoWeasel `mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");` example. so, in place of `$con` must be your connection variable.(`$db`)

Comment: Ah ha, got it! Thank you guys so much! I'll definitely use that line to help troubleshoot in the future.